# Maintenance costs for home geothermal heating & cooling / ground source heat pump systems?

Tags: home-ownership, expenses, utilities

My realtor showed me a brand new house that has a geothermal cooling and heating system built in. I did some online research and here is the link to that builder's [geothermal system explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvrCITL8AsE).

However, I also read that those systems are very expensive to maintain. I really like the house though. Are geothermal systems worth it, financially speaking? They claim to offer savings of up to 80% in the electric bill (you know what that means when they say "UP TO"). What else should I know about these kinds of systems to help me with my purchase decision?

Comment: First, it's almost certainly not a geothermal heating system, but a ground-source heat pump.  True geothermal heating is rare (outside of e.g. Iceland), as you need a hot spring or similar.

Comment: There are some questions related to [geothermal heating on DIY.SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=geothermal).

Comment: Are you suggesting the company whose video was linked, is calling their system by the wrong name? They clearly say geothermal a dozen times.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer It is entirely possible that geothermal in the US does not mean what it means to a physicist or geologist (as jamesqf suggests). The water being pumped up from 150 ft below my neighbor's yard is at 55 degrees F, too cold to wash in, and a heat pump extracts some energy from that, sending back even cooler water. In Iceland, the water can be _too hot to bathe in_ when it comes out of the ground (think of Yellowstone National Park).

Comment: These systems are very commonly called geothermal systems.  And I don't see a problem with the name, either.  Even if the ground temperature is only 55 degF, if you are extracting heat from the Earth, by definition you are using geothermal energy.